# How can I improve this C++ program for Hexadecimal to decimal conversion?

Tags: c++

```
// This is a C++ project for Unit Test 2 (2015-16). This program can convert a hexadecimal number into decimal equivalent.

#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
char choice;
cout<<" *** HEXADECIMAL TO DECIMAL CONVERTER ***";
do{                  //The whole program is inside a do-while loop, so that user can convert a number as many times as they want.
char hexd[120];
                                                         //This string will store the hexadecimal number input by the user.
int validn_count=0,length,lcopy,p=1,num,i,countp=0;
double decimal=0;

do{                                 //This do-while loop checks if the inputed number is valid or not. If not valid it again asks to enter the number.
cout<<"\n Enter a hexadecimal number for conversion (0-F): ";
cin>>hexd;
length=strlen(hexd);
for(int i=0;i<length;++i)
{
    if( (hexd[i]>=48 and hexd[i]<=57) or (hexd[i]>=65 and hexd[i]<=70) or      (hexd[i]>=97 and hexd[i]<=102) or hexd[i]==46)
      ++validn_count;
    else
       {
        validn_count=0;
        cout<<"\n ! WARNING! Invalid HEXADECIMAL NUMBER!!!!";
        break;
       }
}

}while(validn_count==0);




for(i=0;i<length;i++)   //This for loop checks how many characters are there before the decimal point (.)
{
    if(hexd[i]==46)
     break;
   else
     ++countp;


}
lcopy=countp;          // Copying the value of countp for usage in the  conversion.

for(i=0;i<countp;++i)  // This for loop converts all the character before    the decimal point (.) into decimal number and stores it in the variable 'decimal'.
 {
  if(hexd[i]>=48 and hexd[i]<=57)
    num=((int)hexd[i]-48);
  else if(hexd[i]>=65 and hexd[i]<=70)
   num=((int)hexd[i]-55);
  else if (hexd[i]>=97 and hexd[i]<=102)
    num=((int)hexd[i]-87);

 decimal=decimal+(num*pow(16,--lcopy));
 }


for(i=(countp+1);i<length;i++) // This for loop converts all the character after the decimal point (.) into decimal number and further stores it in the variable 'decimal'.
    {

    if(hexd[i]>=48 and hexd[i]<=57)
    num=((int)hexd[i]-48);
   else if(hexd[i]>=65 and hexd[i]<=70)
   num=((int)hexd[i]-55);
   else if (hexd[i]>=97 and hexd[i]<=102)
   num=((int)hexd[i]-87);

   decimal=decimal+(num*pow(16,-p));
    ++p;                                    //p is used for the multiply with 16 with negative powers.
   }


   cout<<" \n The decimal equivalent of hexadecimal number "<<hexd<<" is "    <<decimal;
  cout<<"\n Do you want to convert another hexadecimal number into decimal?   (Y/N): ";  // Asks if the user again wants to do a conversion.
 cin>>choice;
 }while(choice=='Y' or choice=='y');
cout<<"\n\n **** THANK YOU FOR USING THIS SOFTWARE ****";
return 0;
}
```

Logic I have used:

1. First the whole program is inside a do-while loop so that user can convert a number as many time they want.
2. then another do-while loop checks if the inputted number is valid or invalid, if invalid it again asks the user to input.
3. then a for loop counts the no of characters before the decimal point (if any).
4. then another for loop  converts the characters before decimal point into decimal number.
5. then, another for loop converts the characters after decimal point into decimal fraction and adds it the original number.
6. then it prints it and asks if the user wants to again run the loop.

I am a semi beginner in C++ and I got a project In C++ to convert a hexadecimal integer into decimal equivalent, but I extended it and now this program can convert fractional part also.

Can you experts give me some advice on how can I improve this code? I want it to make as much "error proof" as possible.

I have knowledge on selection statements (if-else),  loops (for,while, do-while), operators and other basic things in C++.

Note: This program is compiled with MinGW and CodeBlocks. and my school teacher uses TurboC++.

P.S: My english is poor, it's not my first language, I have written radix point as decimal point....sorry for that.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @zaph The digits after the decimal point.

Comment: @zaph Every digit to the right is 1/radix as big as before. That is how positional notation works.

Comment: There's no decimal point in hexadecimal numbers, at most it's a hexadecimal point or more generally a radix separator. There is nothing wrong with having fractional parts in hexadecimal numbers.

Comment: @zaph Hexadecimal is a number format. It has nothing to do with "underlying bytes". Here's an example: `1.23`. In decimal that would be `1.13671875` (unless I've made a mistake).

Comment: @zaph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation

Comment: @zaph, hexadecimal can be used to represent (binary-encoded) data (and aligns nicely with bytes, as each hexadecimal digit represents *log2(16)=4* bits and a byte is 8 bits), but as any positional number system, it can also be used to represent (some) numbers, namely integers and all those rational numbers that can be expressed with a power of the base (16 for hexadecimal) as the denominator.

Comment: @anuraag-biswas A first, easy **improvement** would be to indent your code correctly. Your IDE (CodeBlocks) probably even provides an action that does this for you.

Comment: While asking for how to improve your code is a good idea, http://stackoverflow.com is the wrong place for it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sorry: I did not read the code closely enough, the question is not about the hex notation we frequently use to represent data bytes but about the base 16 number system.

Comment: @zaph Those are the same thing. (Other than computer-language aspects of a numeral, eg 0x prefix or integer-only.) (A language could allow 0x74A.B and even 0x3Fe2B.)

Comment: Magic numbers. Assumed character encoding. Old-style casts. Obscure variable names. FOR+IF instead of WHILE. Repeated code. Commenting the obvious. Cryptic comments. No loop invariants.

Comment: The gereral usage of hexadecimal in computer programming is a hex-dump of data displayed in hex such as displaying `NSData`, there is underlying base 16, it is individual bytes displayed with two hexadecimal characters. Each hexadecimal character represents 4-bits and there is no other oter interpretation other than the sequence order. There is a less common, in computer programming) yet equally valid usage for base 16 numbers. Example: When I see 12345678 in a hex dump I do not consider them as 0x12 * 0x1000000 + 0x34 * 0x10000 + 0x56 * 0x100 + 0x78. but as 4 hexadecimal represented bytes.

Comment: Use character constants instead of decimal values.  For example, '0' instead of 48 or 0x30.

Comment: A good improvement is to use existing libraries and functions, such as `std::istringstream`.

Comment: @zaph: Another general usage of hexadecimal in computer programming is to denote bit settings for hardware registers.  For example, the status of the receive character register, in a UART, may use bit 0x08 to denote that a character is present (received).

Comment: In embedded systems, a general usage of hexadecimal in computer programming is to denote addresses, such as the location of hardware devices, including FPGA, DMA, Graphics Processors, Interrupt Controllers and memory controllers.

Comment: This algorithm introduces unnecessary round-off errors. Since you are adding small values to a big one, if the range is too large it is the same as adding zero. So if there are enough digits all the ones past a certain point contribute nothing to the sum. Read an introduction to using floating point number asap.

Comment: Holy sh*t, everything in this comment section is blowing my mind!!!!....guys, I already wrote int the description that I am a beginner and this is my first question on StackOverflow, please help me (in a easy way if possible) and please have some pity on me.

Comment: _[Can I post questions about optimizing code on Stack Overflow?....No, it isn't the best place - though it is on-topic, there's a better place for such questions. You can take working code to Code Review - but do make sure to read their help center to see what exactly they expect from a good question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261841/can-i-post-questions-about-optimizing-code-on-stack-overflow)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than using existing libraries, such as `std::istringstream` and `sscanf`, another method is a lookup table (array).

You should also lookup these functions:  `isdigit`, `isxdigit`, `tolower` and `toupper`.

```
static const char char_to_decimal[] = "0123456789";
static const char char_to_hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

char * const p = strchr(char_to_decimal, digit_character);
if (p)
{
  value = p - char_to_decimal;
}
```

To print a hex digit:

```
char hex_digit_char = char_to_hex[digit];
```

Comment: what does static char mean? sorry I am a noob......

Answer (score 0):

I would have done something like this:

```
const char *HexadecimalToDecimal(const char *hexa)
{
    static char str[12];

    unsigned long len = strlen(hexa);

    // skip the initial '0x' if any
    if (len > 2 && hexa[0] == '0' && hexa[1] == 'x')
    {
        hexa += 2;
        len -= 2;
    }

    if (len >0 && len <= 8)
    {
        unsigned int value = 0;

        char c;
        while ((c = *hexa++ | 0x20))
        {
            value <<= 4;

            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                value += c - '0';
            else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
                value += 10 + c - 'a';
            else
                break;
        }

        if (hexa[-1] == 0)
        {
            sprintf(str, "%u", value);
            return str;
        }
    }

    strcpy(str, "err");
    return str;
}
```

thus you can do:

```
fprintf("0xab45F > %s", HexadecimalToDecimal("0xab45F");
```

or even better, if you want test you can define a macro such as:

```
#define hexdec(s) printf(#s " = %s\n", HexadecimalToDecimal(#s))
```

then your main can look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    hexdec(1234);
    hexdec(0x200);
    hexdec(0x516c27f);
    hexdec(ff0000);
    hexdec(0xFFFFFFFF);
    hexdec(0124g); // err
    hexdec(012456789ab); // err
}
```

**explanation:**

- the hexadecimal string can either have a prefix (‘0x’) or not
- it needs to be less than 8 characters (for instance, "0xFFFFFFFF" has
  8 characters and a prefix of 2)
- each character is converted from 0-F to 0-15 and the value is
  multiplied by 16 (shifting the value 4 bits to the left). Then the
  resulting value is converted to a string with the decimal value.

If an error occurs (unexpected character, string too long, etc.) the function returns “err”

Comment: Thanks for answering, but........I am a beginner, everything you wrote flew over my head, I only know upto loops. and the '0x',,,what is that? I didn't get that?

Comment: @AnuraagBiswas well hexadecimal numbers use a prefix to differentiate them from other decimal, octal, binary numbers, and it depends on the language used to develop... for c we prefix hexadecimal numbers with 0x, that's what allows us and the computer for instance to make a difference between the numbers 10 and 0x10 (the latter one equals 16 in fact)

Comment: thank you, and can you tell me the use of static char? I only know char data type

Comment: @AnuraagBiswas the static char was just a way to keep the char array outside the function scope (else it would have been created on the stack) and thus make it available as a result for the calling scope. This is kind of a trick because I was not knowing what are your memory limitations/usage, else I would have used 'new' but with ownership considerations, etc.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use static like that. Either return a `std::string` or take in the output string/buffer as a parameter.

Comment: @NeilKirk I know (blush) but that was the only thing I got to avoid the big memory picture